Could I concatenate two string inputs/values from two separate lists into one other variable?
I want to concatenate to items of a list to create another list with each of these items:
For instance:
answers = ["RAM", "PC", "WAN"]
terms = ["Random Access Memory", "Personal Computer", "Wide Area Network"]

What I want to happen:
combination = [RAM - Random Access Memory]


I believe the zip() function is exactly what you are looking for.

Adding to the comment above, you can use it like so: [f"{left} - {right}" for left, right in zip(answers, terms)]

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour]. The core part of this question has already been asked. If you need help with the rest, you could [edit] this question to show what you tried and where you're stuck. Check out [ask] for more tips.

You would need to clarify exactly what output you want since combination = [RAM - Random Access Memory] isn't valid Python code.

zip() will help out here, which will collect any number of iterables into chunks, ending with the shortest amongst them
>>> for values in zip([1,2], [3,4], [5,6,7]):
...     print(values)
... 
(1, 3, 5)
(2, 4, 6)  # NOTE 7 is lost

There are many routes using this to your result, but a long version may help what's happening be clearer
result = []
for answer, term in zip(answers, terms):  # unpacks tuple as 2 names
    together = f"{answer} - {term}"       # new string
    result.append(together)               # append to list

>>> result
['RAM - Random Access Memory', 'PC - Personal Computer', 'WAN - Wide Area Network']

